# How to remove the channel dimension within a Pytorch Model

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to create a GAN that generates audio data. Using a standard GAN that consists only of Conv2d layers has not provided good results, so I'm trying to add an LSTM layer to the model. However, the output of my last Conv2d layer shape is (None, 1 ,256, 64). This is not a valid shape for the LSTM layer and I'm trying to drop the "1" dim of the previous layer, as I don't think it is needed.

I've tried torch.reshape, torch.squeeze, and just indexing the tensor to remove that dim, but all result in shape errors.

How can I add an LSTM layer to this model, and input the correct shape?

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_noise, channels_img, features_g):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            # Input: N x channels_noise x 1 x 1
            self._block(channels_noise, features_g * 16, (16,4), 1, 0),  # img: 4x4
            self._block(features_g * 16, features_g * 8, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 8x8
            self._block(features_g * 8, features_g * 4, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 16x16
            self._block(features_g * 4, features_g * 2, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 32x32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                features_g * 2, channels_img, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1
            ),
            
            # Output: N x channels_img x 64 x 64
            nn.Tanh(),
        )
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=64, hidden_size=10)

    def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, bias=False,
            ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
    

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.net(x)
        x = x[:,0,:,:]
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        return lstm_out
```

Comment: `x = torch.rand( (10, 1, 256, 64) )` then `x.squeeze(1).shape`
`torch.Size([10, 256, 64])`, also try looking at the `batch first` argument for the lstm